# VB.NET Database Query to Chart a Quantity Vs Date

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a table in an Access database with information like the following:

DATE   SERIAL   RESULT
1/5/2016    5299    PASS
1/5/2016    5371    PASS
1/6/2016    5280    PASS
1/6/2016    3962    FAIL
1/7/2016    1325    PASS

I'm trying to run a query to display a count of the SERIAL's that have a RESULT of "PASS" and plot them for each day. The closest I have managed to get is the following:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim query As String
Dim FullDatabasePath As String = "C:\db.accdb"
Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Dim dbSource As String = " Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath
Dim table As String = "tblQA"

query = "SELECT [DATE], (SELECT COUNT([SERIAL]) FROM " & table & " WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN #" & dtpFrom.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & dtpTo.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND RESULT = 'PASS') as RowCount FROM [" & table & "] WHERE DATE BETWEEN #" & dtpFrom.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & dtpTo.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND RESULT = 'PASS'"

Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
ds.Clear()

con.Open()
da.Fill(ds, table)
con.Close()

Chart1.Series.Add("PASS")

Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables(table)
Chart1.Series("PASS").XValueMember = "DATE"
Chart1.Series("PASS").YValueMembers = "RowCount"
```

- If I select 1/5/2016 for both start and end dates using the DateTimePickers on my form (dtpFrom and dtpTo), my chart shows me 2 serials on 1/5/2016. Likewise, it shows 1 serial if I choose a start and end date of 1/6/2015. (yay)
- If choosing a start date of 1/5/2016 and end date of 1/7/2016, it shows 4 serials on each of those 3 days. (boo)

How can I make it not accumulate, but instead display the number of passing serials for each day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this SQL will do what you want:

```
SELECT [DATE], COUNT(RESULT) 
FROM Table_1   
where result = 'PASS' AND [Date] BETWEEN '20160501' AND '20160701'  
group by [date]
```

EDIT: The dates are formatted to suit MS T-SQL - you'll have to tweak these to suit Access ( and your dtp's) of course.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It is working perfectly now. Counting the pass results and grouping by date makes sense, in hindsight. I don't even need to worry about what the serial numbers are. I translated your code to the following to make it compatible with my code from above:    

`query = "SELECT [DATE], COUNT(RESULT) AS RESULTCOUNT FROM " & table & " WHERE RESULT = 'PASS' AND [DATE] BETWEEN #" & dtpFrom.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & dtpTo.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# GROUP BY [DATE]"`

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of completeness I've added a note about the date formatting to my answer.